# How to show the popup window in top of the parent window?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I want to show a popup window in button click event on the top of the parent window.
Even I use `Window.Focus()` method but the pop up window goes back to the parent window.

Please help me on this .thanks in Advance.

Comment: You might want to accept some other answers as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a model popup of AJAX, take a look on this...

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/ajax-control-toolkit/modalpopup/launching-a-modal-popup-window-from-server-code-cs

Comment: Which is of course the right way to solve the problem - what Muhammad forgot to mention is that you can#t control the Z-order of different browser windows from Javascript nor HTML

Answer (score 0):

use css property z-index for it. like you can give 10 z-index to the popup model